# how do I read videos from a file and use ffmpeg to save each video with different bit rate?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-encoding

I want to use the UGC dataset and after reading each video, save each video with a different bitrate and plot the R-D curve. for this aim, I want to use FFmpeg and automatically do the mentioned things. for this what should I do? I am a beginner in encoding and decoding the videos? is it possible to calculate PSNR with each rate for videos using FFmpeg? I find this command line code that calculates the PSNR  and VMAF:

```
ffmpeg -i encode.mp4 -i reference.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920x1080:flags=bicubic[main]; [1:v]scale=1920x1080:flags=bicubic,format=pix_fmts=yuv420p,fps=fps=25/1[ref]; [main][ref]libvmaf=psnr=1:phone_model=1:log_fmt=json" -f null - > out.json;
```

but I do not know how can I do this for videos with different bit-rate. could you please help me? especially in plotting the r-d curve.
Thank you.

Comment: Output each video with a different bitrate, then run libvmaf on each separately.

Comment: Thank you. could you please introduce me to a link or tutorial for more examples about this issue? because I am a beginner and I do not have enough information about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output each video with a different bitrate:

```
ffmpeg -i input -b:v 1000k encode1
ffmpeg -i input -b:v 2000k encode2
ffmpeg -i input -b:v 3000k encode3
```

Then run libvmaf on each separately:

```
ffmpeg -i encode1 -i reference.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]libvmaf=psnr=1:phone_model=1:log_fmt=json" -f null - > out1.json
ffmpeg -i encode2 -i reference.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]libvmaf=psnr=1:phone_model=1:log_fmt=json" -f null - > out2.json
ffmpeg -i encode3 -i reference.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]libvmaf=psnr=1:phone_model=1:log_fmt=json" -f null - > out2.json
```

Comment: I used the above code but running libvmaf produced the following error: ~
libvmaf WARNING could not read model from path: "/usr/local/share/model/vmaf_v0.6.1.pkl"
libvmaf WARNING pkl model files have been deprecated, use json
libvmaf ERROR problem loading model file: /usr/local/share/model/vmaf_v0.6.1.pkl
[Parsed_libvmaf_0 @ 00000249ce81ee80] libvmaf encountered an error, check log for details
Error while filtering: Invalid argument
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
Conversion failed!~

Comment: @Negin See [Using VMAF with FFmpeg](https://github.com/Netflix/vmaf/blob/master/resource/doc/ffmpeg.md), or just download [vmaf_v0.6.1.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Netflix/vmaf/master/model/vmaf_v0.6.1.json), put it in the same folder as your video files, then use `libvmaf=model_path=vmaf_v0.6.1.json:psnr=1:phone_model=1:log_fmt=json:log_path=vmaf.log`